# LocalDate.EPOCH is not available

Tags: java, localdate

I need to normalise some Data to execute a SQL-Statement. Unfortunately I can't initialize a LocalDate-variable with LocalDate.EPOCH. MIN and MAX are working.

```
startDatum = startDatum == null? LocalDate.EPOCH : startDatum; // doesn't work
endDatum = (endDatum == null)? LocalDate.MAX : endDatum; // works
```

Eclipse only says `EPOCH cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: `EPOCH` was introduced in Java 9, so if you are targeting Java 8 it is not available.

Comment: `LocalDate.EPOCH` is just a (confusing) symbol for the arbitrary date 1970-01-01. Why do you want to choose this date as start in case of missing content? I don't understand your use-case.

Comment: @MenoHochschild the query returns bills starting at about 1990. I won't need exactly the begin of unixtime, but i found this as a good predefined date to get **all** bills returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `EPOCH` field on `LocalDate` was new in Java 9. If you're using Java 8, you can do the following to get the `LocalDate` at epoch:

```
LocalDate.ofEpochDay(0)
```

Comment: [Looks like there is.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#EPOCH)

Comment: Oh wow... thats a bit embarrassing. Our project is at Java 8. My problem was that I'm using jdk-11 as source view in Eclipse and even looking in the Java 11 API because of the livesearch field. Thank you!